# Async object Promise as Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, teamspeak

why do i become when i run this function as callback [object Promise] ? i use the Ts3 nodejs framework by Miltivit4min ([Github](https://github.com/Multivit4min/TS3-NodeJS-Library))

here some code i tried (return value = [object Promise])

```
async function getChannelName(cid) {

   await teamspeak.getChannelByID(cid).then(data => {

    return data.name;

   });

};
```

how can i convert this value to a string with a value like "My cool Channel"

best regards

Comment: You don't return the awaited result, and you're needlessly mixing `await` and `.then`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Don't mixup `async-await` with `Promise.then` @F.Ghost Use `const data = await teamspeak.getChannelByID(cid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async` function always returns a `Promise` by design and your `getChannelName` function has no return statement, so the promise is never resolved. Also you are mixing up some `await` and `.then()` syntax, you only need one of them.

```
async function getChannelName(cid) {
   const data = await teamspeak.getChannelByID(cid);
   return data.name;
};


const name = await getChannelName(123); // name has the channel name
```